# Providing login and password through c++ like expect script in Unix/Linux

Tags: c++, c, ssh, ipc, unix

**Problem ::**

I want to remote login to a server by SSH and execute some commands and retrieve output of the excuted commands.

**Solution ::**

I have achieved the same using my "expect script" in my perl script and then do processing on it. But , it is too slow , takes around 10 seconds to get PID of a remote process and then check its memory and CPU usage.

Generating rsa ID using ssh-keygen is an option , but bidirectional communication still remeins a problem.

**Requirement ::**

Is it possible to acheive the same in C/C++ without using any extra libraries using pipe or FIFO ?

Popen() seemed to be an option but it is only unidirectional (Bidirectional exists for only *BSD) and using FIFO , i dont know how to make the ssh commands input and output attach to the FIFO and also SSH command requires login and password always from the Terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would fork() and exec() do the trick ? If I dup2() the stdin and stdout of the child process and then exec the SSH command.

Comment: The real question is what's making your script slow: execution speed, bandwidth, or latency. But this is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it takes a *lot* of work and a complete program to do this is too long to post here. Especially I/O buffering should be taken into account when reading and writing are interleaved. A single write phase followed by a single read phase would be pretty easy, though.

In any case, I'd recommend using a [socketpair](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html) instead of pipes. These permit bidirectional communication, while pipes are unidirectional (so you need two pipes, i.e. four file descriptors).

```
enum { FROMCHILD = 0, TOCHILD = 1 };
int fd[2];
socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fd); // check for errors

switch (fork()) {
  case -1:
    // handle error
  case 0:
    // child
    dup2(fd[TOCHILD],   0);
    dup2(fd[FROMCHILD], 1);
    // try to exec
    _exit(1);
  default:
    // parent: we may read from fd[FROMCHILD] and write to fd[TOCHILD]
}
```

Also, make sure you get the quoting right if you need to construct/parse the SSH command into an `argv`-style buffer. Check out [`quote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master/quote.c) from [Git](http://git-scm.com) if you need example code (or a discussion of the issues).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will take some time to implement it with the timeline I am having .